# How do I create a virtual box vm network with internet access that is safe for my physical PC and network?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I am trying to create a network of 1 Server and 2 Nodes in virtual box. I am new to networking in virtual box and have read the docs. How do I create the desired network but protect my physical computer from activity on the VMs? I have networked the Server and Nodes with a virtual network adapter set to Host-only adapter which I am told is safe but now those devices have no internet connection. In short my goal is to keep my PC safe from risky VMs, but give those vms internet access so I can update their software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you want to prevent the VMs from communicating with your host's LAN, while still keeping Internet access. I'm not sure if there's a clean way to achieve this.

You could create an additional VM and make it your router/firewall. You'll need two network interfaces in that one: one set to type "NAT", the other one to "Internal network". Then configure network adapters in other VMs to "Internal network". You'll have to set the same name of the internal network in all VMs.

Then proceed to install a router OS onto your new VM. I prefer OPNsense, but other alternatives include pfSense and OpenWRT. Configure the NAT interface as WAN and internal network interface as LAN (the order may be different than in VBox settings, but you can find out which one is which by checking their MAC addresses). Set up LAN to use eg. IP `192.168.123.1` for the router, with mask `/24` (`255.255.255.0` in the long notation) and enable DHCP.

At this point your other VMs should be able to receive their IP addresses and access the Internet, but they're not yet isolated from the host. That must be done in the firewall settings. In OPNsense you would add a following rule on the LAN interface (or a floating rule):

- source: LAN
- destination: your host's network, probably something like `192.168.x.0/24` - check host's IP
- quick: enabled
- action: reject

Save the rule and apply settings. Test with a risk-free VM first.